# border-radius with dropdown menu

Tags: html, css

I have created a dropdown menu using transitions and border-radius. The dropdown menu works perfectly and behaves as expected but on a blue background color I see a white border.

Please open this site http://www.mgv-harmonia1866.de/gaestebuch/

so please hover on the menu and go to "Kontakt" and hover on the list.

The CSS:
http://www.mgv-harmonia1866.de/Ressourcen/CSS/mgv.css

Thank you!

Comment: I don't see any white border on the "Veranstaltungen" or "Kontakt" menus over the blue background of the page you linked.  It's just rounded grey boxes that go darker on hover...  looks pretty clean to me.  I'm using Chromium 37.0.2062.120.

Comment: I agree with @Chad, I can see a few pixels of anti-aliasing, but nothing else.  Can you tell us what browser your using and provide a screenshot of what you see?

Comment: I'm the same as @Chad and Adam, on both Chrome 37 and Firefox 42.0

Comment: Are you sure? I have just made a screenshot http://www.mgv-harmonia1866.de/screenshot.png

Comment: @Dom85, thats the browser's antialiasing for the rounded border.  There is no way to remove those few pixels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
#Navigation > li > ul > li { overflow: hidden;}
#Navigation > li > ul > li > a { border-radius: 0; //remove border-radius}
```

Comment: Hello Stepan Lylak! Thanks for your reply! This really helped! :-) Thank you very much! :-)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use overflow hidden. Just remove the background from the inner li and add it to the normal status of the a:

```
#Navigation li > ul li { 
    background: transparent;
}
#Navigation li > ul li a {
    background: linear-gradient(#efefef,#bbbbbb);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#efefef,#bbbbbb);
}
#Navigation li > ul li a:hover {
    background: linear-gradient(#4b545f,#4b545f);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#4b545f,#4b545f);
}
```

That border is because you are seeing the gradient background of the `li` behing the solid gray background of the `a`.

Edited to add the hover state.

Comment: Hi, when using this the transition effect does not work.

Comment: I suppose that you should add the background for the hover also with gradient to let the transition property work properly

Comment: I am testing this with the main navigation but the transition effect does not work. Any ideas?

Comment: The problem is that transition does not work together with linear-gradient. Tested with current Chrome version.